# Solve for x: $(x^2-3x+1)^2-3(x^2-3x+1)+1=x$

Tags: functions, roots, factoring

> Solve the equation for $x$: $$(x^2-3x+1)^2-3(x^2-3x+1)+1=x$$

I've tried to solve by:

Let $y=(x^2-3x+1)$

So,
$$y^2-3y+1=x$$

But still have one $x$ and it's not factorable!

What do I do to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: $y = f(x), (f\circ f)(x) = x$ There is there is a solution when $f(x) =x, (x^2 - 4x+ 1) = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: you are halfway there.

$$
x^2 - 3x + 1 = y \\
y^2 - 3y + 1 = x
$$

Subtract:

$$(y-x)(y+x-2)=0$$

The latter gives two quadratics in $x$.

Comment: Could you tell me why I should subtract? Thanks

Comment: Once you notice the symmetry of the equations, it becomes obvious that $y=x$ is a solution. Subtracting makes it easier to factor out $y-x$ and isolate the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $y- x= x^2 -y^2-3(x-y)$ . Can you continue?

Comment: $(x-y)(x+y-2)=0$ I am not sure how i can continue after

Comment: $y = x^2 - 3x + 1$ put that polynomial back in for y.  Now you have two quadratics.  What can you do with quadratics?

Comment: Would it be $-(x^2-4x+1)(x-1)^2$?